# Wrong formatting in Winform DataGridView for DateTime type

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datetime-format

I am using dot net 3.5 in a project and need to bind a DateTime type value in a DataGridView.

My culture is set as SV-Swedish and I have set the ShortTime format as - **'kl 'H:mm** and LongTime format as - **'kl 'H:mm:ss**

According to Microsoft https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.90).aspx

> DateTime.ToString(), combines the custom format strings returned by
>   the ShortDatePattern and LongTimePattern properties of the
>   DateTimeFormatInfo object returned by the
>   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat property

and when checking through code or intermediate window, its working what it said like (**"2018-07-25 kl 15:45:49"**).
But when I bind the same DateTime value to a DataGridView column, it shows value in the format - **2018-07-26 15:55**.
Screenshot attached below.

My code is simple like -

```
        List<Data> dataSource = new List<Data>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
        {
            dataSource.Add(new Data() { Id = i, DateOfJoining = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i), Department =  "Department " + i, Name =  "Name " + 1});
        }
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSource;
```

and the Data class is -

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfJoining { get; set; }
}
```

I tested the same scenario in 4.6.1 and this is working fine according to what is set in the System culture settings.

Can anyone explain this strange behavior in Dot net 3.5 ?

Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you set

```
dataGridView1.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyy-MM-dd kl H:mm:ss";
```

or perhaps extend your Data class so that it also holds the date in the desired format.

Comment: This could be one work-around. but the problem is, this format is applicable all over the application, and its not feasible to set everywhere.